# pytest how to run tests / django

Tags: python, django, pycharm, pytest

I'm trying to use pytest for the 1st time in my new created app but i'm facing problems with running it. I still receive 'no tests ran in...' message.

My project name is PROJECT, then is my app called `diet_app` and file `tests.py` inside the app folder.

How to run tests?

I tried with:

- `pytest`
- `pytest tests`
- `pytest diet_app`

To be more precise - to install PyTest I used:

```
pip install pytest
pip install pytest-django
```

I'm working in PyCharm

Comment: Did you read the `pytest-django` docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pytest-django doesn't actually find tests in a file called `tests.py` out of the box. If you want to keep using a file called `tests.py` [you'll need to add a `pytest.ini` file in your top-level directory](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#faq-tests-not-being-picked-up):

> **My tests are not being found. Why?**
>
> By default, pytest looks for tests in files named `test_*.py` (note that this is not the same as `test*.py`) and `*_test.py`. If you have your tests in files with other names, they will not be collected. Note that Django’s startapp manage command creates an `app_dir/tests.py` file. Also, it is common to put tests under `app_dir/tests/views.py`, etc.
>
> To find those tests, create a `pytest.ini` file in your project root and add an appropriate `python_files` line to it:
>
> ```
> [pytest]
> python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
> ```